# Existe alguma maneira de definir um Título específico nas rotas do Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-rotas

No `Laravel` 5, estou criando um menu dinamicamente, fazendo um `foreach`  na lista de rotas registradas.

Assim, eu posso ter um menu sendo exibido cada vez que uma rota nova é criada, porém estou estou listando apenas os que `contém` o método `index` no controller.

Assim:

```
@foreach(Route::getRoutes() as $route)
 @if(Str::finish($route->getName(), '.index'))
 <li>
   {{ link_to_route($route->getName()) }}
 </li>
 @endif
@endforeach
```

Porém, no segundo parâmetro de `link_to_route`, seria interessante passar um título para essa rota. Assim eu teria os links com o nome bem descritivo para a rota, ao invés de exibir a `url` completa.

Existe alguma maneira de, na criação da `Rota`, criar um título para essa rota (não estou falando da opção `"as"` que é usada internamente)?

Existe alguma  maneira de definir no método do controller ou na rota um atributo para que eu use como titulo da `Route`? Posso fazer isso em `Laravel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, com um pouco de criatividade você pode criar "atributos personalizados" no `Laravel`. Quero dizer com isso que você pode criar índices  no `array` passado para a rota.

Minha sugestão é fazer isso com índices que **não são usados** no `Laravel` internamente.

Por exemplo, poderia-se utilizar tranquilamente o atributo `title`.

Assim, podemos fazer da seguinte forma:

```
  Route::get('/', [
    'uses' => 'HomeController@getIndex', 'title' => 'Página inicial'
  ]);

  Route::get('/usuarios', [
     'uses' => 'UsersController@getIndex', 'title' => 'Página de usuários'
  ]);

 // Observe que não defini `title` aqui

 Route::post('/usuario/cadastrar', ['uses' => 'UserController@postStore']);
```

Em seguida, poderíamos fazer da seguinte forma na view, para poder listar apenas `rotas` que contenham título:

```
 @foreach(Route::getRoutes() as $route)
     @if(array_key_exists('title', $action = $route->getAction()))
         {{ link_to_route($route->getName(), $action['title']) }}
     @endif
 @endforeach
```

Observe que só são exibidas as rotas que contenha o índice `title`. Ou seja, as demais são puladas.

Creio que essa é a melhor maneira de criar seus menus dinamicamente com o `Laravel`.

Espero que isso possa ajudar a muitos :)

Comment: Muito interessante @WallaceMaxters, acho que isso pode simplificar algo que eu estava fazendo na minha aplicação... como eu faço pra exibir esse atributo personalizado na view q eu carreguei? TIpo, quando eu acessar a home eu puxar o title dentro de um <h1> por exemplo

Comment: basta colocar {{ $action['title'] }} ?

Comment: @RaylanSoares observe que no `if` que tem o `array_keys_exists` eu crio a variável `$action` dentro do `if`. Isso para não chamar o método `$route->getAction()` duas vezes...